# Does the django authentication logout function delete's session row in django_session table?

Tags: python, django

I am implementing a basic login and logout page using django. My login function adds a row into the django_session table in db. However, when I logout, it doesn't remove the session row. Since the session is no longer valid and all the session related data is removed from the request, shouldn't the logout function also remove the session row from the django_session table?

Here is my logout function:

```
@login_required
def logout_student(request):
    logout(request)
    # Redirect to a success page.
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/index/')
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you manually adds a row to `django_session` on login, then on [`django.contrib.auth.logout()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.logout), the [`request.session.flush()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.flush)) function will **only** delete the row with the same primary key `session_key` as the current session key from `django_session` table.

`request.session.flush()` is used to ensure that the previous session data can’t be accessed again from the user’s browser. It basically does two things:

1. delete the current session data from the database (or cache, depends on which one you choose for your [session backends](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/)).
2. regenerate the session key value that is sent back to the user in the cookie.

The Django source code of `django.contrib.auth.logout()`:

```
def logout(request):
    """
    Removes the authenticated user's ID from the request and flushes their
    session data.
    """
    # Dispatch the signal before the user is logged out so the receivers have a
    # chance to find out *who* logged out.
    user = getattr(request, 'user', None)
    if hasattr(user, 'is_authenticated') and not user.is_authenticated():
        user = None
    user_logged_out.send(sender=user.__class__, request=request, user=user)

    request.session.flush()
    if hasattr(request, 'user'):
        from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser
        request.user = AnonymousUser()
```

Delete method for database-based session:

```
def delete(self, session_key=None):
    if session_key is None:
        if self.session_key is None:
            return
        session_key = self.session_key
    try:
        Session.objects.get(session_key=session_key).delete()
    except Session.DoesNotExist:
        pass
```

To remove the manually added row, you can utilize Django signal [`django.contrib.auth.signals.user_logged_out`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.django.contrib.auth.signals.user_logged_out) to delete row on user logout.

Answer (score 3):

It does not delete the session row, so the sessions can be audited at a later point.  You have to clean the rows up manually by using (for example) a custom management command and cron.

Answer (score 0):

- session is neither deleted nor invalidated upon user logout. Session data (eg user set language) still available in request
- session becomes invalid only when expired or deleted (automatically or by hands)
- to cleanup expired sessions, run **./manage.py cleanup**

it is really strange that you manipulate sessions at database level. It doesn't make sense for me to delete or invalidate session on logout. I would also recommend to use Django generic [logout view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.logout) or [django-registration](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration) and handle custom logic (if any) in signals

Comment: I don't think that's true, `request.session.flush()` will delete the session row from the db/cache. It is only the session cookie stored at the client side that still persists until expiration. But that's not what @deelaws meant.

Comment: And, to cleanup expired sessions, the command should be `django-admin.py cleanup` instead of `manage.py cleanup`

Comment: I was thinking of using the generic logout function but decided not to. I was just wondering why the logout function in my view from the django auth doesn't remove the session_key from the table when the user logout. I didn't know I had to do it manually using request.session.flush(). Got it!

Comment: @deelaws if you are not using `django.contrib.auth.logout()` then yes, you will need to manually call `request.session.flush()`. Though I can't think of any reason not to use the generic ones :)