# Django/Auth: logout clears the session data?

Tags: django, session-variables, django-authentication, django-sessions

I would like to know if [auth.logout](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.3/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L71) clears *session* data or i have to do it by my self.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib import auth
@login_required
def logout(request):
    auth.logout(request)
    return redirect('base:homepage')
```

Something like this...

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib import auth

@login_required
def logout(request):
    for sesskey in request.session.keys():
        del request.session[sesskey]
    auth.logout(request)
    return redirect('base:homepage')
```

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does the django authentication logout function delete's session row in django\_session table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574459/does-the-django-authentication-logout-function-deletes-session-row-in-django-se)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes. Logout flushes the session.

This is [its source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py#L89):

```
def logout(request):
    """
    Removes the authenticated user's ID from the request and flushes their
    session data.
    """
    # Dispatch the signal before the user is logged out so the receivers have a
    # chance to find out *who* logged out.
    user = getattr(request, 'user', None)
    if hasattr(user, 'is_authenticated') and not user.is_authenticated():
        user = None
    user_logged_out.send(sender=user.__class__, request=request, user=user)

    request.session.flush()
    if hasattr(request, 'user'):
        from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser
        request.user = AnonymousUser()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean deleting the record in 'django_session' table by clearing session data, I'm afraid logout function does not do that.

Usually, we have to clear expired session records in 'django_session' table by other ways. Like crontab task to run 'python manage.py clearsessions' periodically

[See this](https://github.com/django/channels/issues/477) for more information.